# conda skeleton cran uses wrong version of R

Tags: python, r, conda, bioconductor

I am trying to package some R packages from CRAN to use in a conda environment because I am using a combination of Python and R packages for a bioinformatics pipeline. Because of other dependencies, I need to keep R at version 3.3

I made a brandnew environment with the version of Python and R I want:

$ conda create -n bioinfo python=3.6.3 r=3.3.2

There is no R installed in the root environment. Then I follow the instructions for conda skeleton:

(bioinfo)$ conda skeleton cran rootSolve

(bioinfo)$ conda skeleton cran rootSolve

(bioinfo)$ conda build r-rootsolve

For some reason, this keeps coming up with an R3.4 dependency, even though according to CRAN, the rootSolve package only needs R>=2.01! Where is this coming from??

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
    r-base:                 3.4.2-haf99962_0

Though building the package does not actually change the version of R running in my environment, the package does not load. Any ideas, please?

R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) -- "Sincere Pumpkin Patch"

```
> library('rootSolve')
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/people/bioc1402/miniconda3/envs/bioinfo2/lib/R/library/rootSolve/libs/rootSolve.so':
  /usr/people/bioc1402/miniconda3/envs/bioinfo2/lib/R/library/rootSolve/libs/rootSolve.so: undefined symbol: R_ExternalPtrAddrFn
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘rootSolve’ was built under R version 3.4.2 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rootSolve’
```

Comment: I must have said a half-dozen times here before but mixing Conda and CRAN seems not to work too well.  I'd just avoid mising them if you can.

Comment: OK, but what do you suggest if you want to publish a Jupyter notebook workflow that is mostly Python packages but involves some R?

Comment: Use R and packages from CRAN.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this was a bug, now fixed in conda-build 3.1.3,
https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/2562

Thanks conda team!

'conda build r-rootsolve --R=3.3.1' now works appropriately with the recipe generated by conda skeleton.